# ValueError when converting a datetime into int in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to cast start time as int add it to the data frame and then draw a scatterplot.

```
test_df['Start'] = test_df['start'].astype(np.int64)
icma_df.plot.scatter(x='Start', y='marks').convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

the above code gives the following error.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '29 Jan 2016  06:56'
```

Answer (score 2):

`'29 Jan 2016  06:56'` is not a pandas/numpy datetime but a string. Convert your `'start'` into a datetime with `pd.to_datetime` first.

Comment: how important is the code .convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) at the end of the 2nd line by taking this off I don't get an error otherwise i get an error. the following one                                                                      AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'

Comment: convert_objects applies to a DataFrame, not against an AxesSubplot returned by plot.scatter. Trust the error messages you receive from the interpreter, python is good at that: it is telling you in plain English you try to call convert_objects against AxesSubplot object that doesn't have this method.